# eliminate duplicate rows using distinct not working sql

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, distinct

I have a query  which is giving me duplicate records . However i tried to use distint on it, but it didnt eliminate duplicate rows.

Below is the query and the results im talking about

```
SELECT 
    f182.ba_id intBc, 
    bo_name.index_name nvrC 
from f182 inner join bo_name ON 
    bo_name.ba_id = f182.ba_id 
    AND bo_name.name_type_code = '0001'
    AND bo_name.indx_name_e_dte IS   NULL 
    and f182.ba_id =114246
```

Even after using distinct at begining, it gives the same result of duplicate rows as there are 2 duplicate records on bo_name matching ba_id

Table with columns and their values are

```
 f182(ba_type_code,ba_id) 
   values
  (0001,114246)
```

other table data is like below :

```
bo_name  ( BA_TYPE_CODE,BA_ID,NAME_TYPE_CODE,indx_name_e_dte,index_name,date)
        values 
        (0001,114246,0001,NULL,abc,11/1/2010)
        (0001,114246,0001,NULL,abc,11/2/2016)
```

I tried to use distinct, still it gives same duplicate rows.

Comment: One of those strings is not the same, check the ascii values for non-printable characters and Unicode equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT f182.ba_id intBc,bo_name.index_name nvrC from f182 
inner join bo_name 
                  ON bo_name.ba_id = f182.ba_id     
                  AND bo_name.name_type_code = '0001'
                  AND bo_name.indx_name IS   NULL and  f182.ba_id =114246
```

Try this